# Assinging a variable for date

Tags: php, date, pagination, assign

I need to assign a specific number like 1559 to today's date and calculate the previous and next days according to this.  For example 2 days ago is 1557, yesterday is 1558, today is 1559 tomorrow is 1560, etc.  With that, i will create a pagination for the days with post method.  My date is in YYYY-MM-DD format and stored in a date variable in mySQL. What should I do to assing numbers to dates and calculate the dates accordingly?

my code looks like this btw:

include ('connect.php');

```
    date_default_timezone_set("Etc/GMT+7");
    $timestamp= date("Y-m-d");
    $day1=1357;

    echo ('<form action="total_inf.php" method="post" name="inf_day">');
    for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)

    {
    $newdate=strtotime('-$i days',strtotime($timestamp));
    $newdate = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $newdate );

    $prevdays=$day1-$i;

    print ('<input type="submit" name="bugun" value="'.$prevdays.'">&nbsp;');

    }
    echo ('</form>');       

    $day_selected=$_POST[bugun];

    $sql1="SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE zaman='$timestamp'";
    $result1=mysql_query($sql1,$conn);
```

Comment: why not use a proper full date?

Answer (score 0):

```
$current_date = new DateTime('2011-08-10');
$current_date->modify('+1 day'); //next day
$current_date->modify('-1 day');// prev day 

$other_date = new DateTime('1970-01-01'); //another date
```

See [DateTime reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

**UPDATE:**

```
$day1 = new DateTime();
$day1->modify('-1357 days'); 
//if you need it to be some fixed date, use $day1= new DateTime("2011-08-01");

$now_date = new DateTime();
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    $date_diff = $now_date->diff($zero_date);
    $prevdays = $date_diff->format("#a")-$i;
    print ('<input type="submit" name="bugun" value="'.$prevdays.'">&nbsp;');
}
```

Works with PHP >= 5.3.0. See [DateInterval::format](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.sub.php)

Comment: John, thank you for your help, but I didn't get how I will produce something like "Day 1550" from today's date thus making it a reference day, and calculating tomorrow as Day 1551 and yesterday as Day 1549.  And calculate this for the coming hundreds of days. My code looks like this btw: